# How can I test that a Promise is never fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

I'm testing a library I wrote to throttle execution of a function.

The API is throttler.do(fn) and it returns a promise of fn's return value (resolved at whichever point the throttler decides it's ok to run it).

I'm using [lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex) to fake `Date()` and `setTimeout` so if I set the throttler to allow two actions per minute and do

```
throttler.do(() => {});
throttler.do(() => {});
throttler.do(() => {}).should.eventually.equal(5);
```

this fails as expected (it times out because it's waiting on the last promise forever since I never call `lolex.tick`).

Is there a way I can turn this into a passing test, something like

```
throttler.do(() => {}).should.never.be.fulfilled;
```

I can't do

```
setTimeout(() => done(), 1500)
```

because the setTimeout method is faked by lolex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the Promise to be synchronous and then check the Promise state. Here is a library you can use [promise-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-sync)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?  I get the idea behind the library but I'm not sure how to apply it. In my case the promise is returned by the subject under test. If I mock what the subject under test returns then I can't really test it.

Comment: How does he create the Promise? You can mock the Promise factory, if you use the Q to defer a promise you can mock that

Comment: Got it - that's much better than my approach, thanks.